# Commit Folder From Local Directory to Online Using SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm completely new to subversion and I'm unsure how to add and commit a Java Project to an online repository using svn. The goal is to move the important folders in the project including the src, package, and class. I've accessed the online repo and I (assume) I have it as a working copy. When I try to svn add the local project folders however, I am told it is not a working copy. How do I fix this? Is there a way I can make my workspace be the online repo directly? Or do I just copy the folder somehow? I'm using Cygwin and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To add your project to svn you can do it this way:

Right click on your project and select: Team / Share Project... 
Select SVN 
Select Use Existing Repository Location
Browse to the location you would like your project to reside: typically .../trunk
Click OK and finish

This should have committed your project to SVN. Regarding your question about your entire workspace being the online repo. with each of your individual projects connected to SVN just like I detailed above, you will be able to commit and update your local projects into and from SVN without any issues.